# In R, how do I extract the column number of a certain row in an array that's closest to a certain value?

Tags: arrays, r, statistics, extract

Given:

```
data(veteran)
library(survival)
veteran$prognostic_indicator <- 0
veteran$prognostic_indicator[veteran$karno<50] <- 1
model <- coxph(Surv(time,status)~age+prognostic_indicator,data=veteran)
library(obsSens)
object <- obsSensSCC(model, which = "prognostic_indicator", g0 = seq(1,10,0.01),p0 = c(0.05,0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4), p1 = seq(0, 1, 0.05), logHaz = FALSE, method = "approx")
```

I can extract the vector:

```
object$lcl[21,1,1:901]
```

Which is ordered by descending values. I want to extract the "name" of the number which is closest to 1, but above it. In that case I want to extract the name "2.69" or position 170 since the corresponding number is 1.0001292. The number at position 2.70 is 0.9968844 and thus too low.

**How do I extract the position (or name) in a vector of descending values where the number is nearest the value 1.0, but above?**

Comment: Yes I agree completely. Got a bit caught up in it. Tried to revise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a new vector with that value,  then identify the first element that satisfies the condition, then move one back in the sequence.

```
obj <- object$lcl[21,1,1:901] 
obj[which(obj< 1)[1] -1]

#    2.69 
#1.000129
```

The other way would be to work on the reversed vector. Then you do not need to backtrack:

```
> rev(obj)[which(rev(obj) > 1)[1] ]
    2.69 
1.000129
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way in addition to DWin's cleaner method.

```
which.min(subset(object$lcl[21,1,1:901], object$lcl[21,1,1:901] > 1) - 1)
```